# kube-service-catalog pods are in "CrashLoopBackOff" state when internet is disabled

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, openshift, openshift-3, okd

Am trying to install opensource version of openshift origin i.e. OKD v3.11 without internet using ansible.
During the complete installation process my internet is disabled on the environment. After the successful installation, I observe that the two pods in **kube-service-catalog** namespace namely **apiserver** and **controller-manager** aren't running. After investigating the playbooks, I discover the playbooks generate API Server keys.

Does the generation of API server keys expect a active internet connection? Is there any internet dependency for the apiserver and controller-manager pods to be in running state?

**I tried:-**
Enabling the internet and redeploying the pods of the kube-service-catalog namespace.
They were in the running state without any restart **as expected**.

**Expected behaviour:-**
The two pods in the kube-service-catalog namespace should be stable and be in the **Running** state with **internet disabled**.

**Actual behaviour:-**
The two pods in the kube-service-catalog namespace are in **CrashLoopBackOff** state.

**Version:-**
 OKD- 3.11, ansible- 2.9

**Logs of apiserver pod:-**

```
I0512 04:53:30.258151       1 feature_gate.go:194] feature gates: map[OriginatingIdentity:true NamespacedServiceBroker:true]
I0512 04:53:30.258177       1 hyperkube.go:192] Service Catalog version v3.11.0-0.1.35+8d4f895-2;Upstream:v0.1.35 (built 2019-01-08T23:12:26Z)
W0512 04:53:31.020172       1 util.go:112] OpenAPI spec will not be served
I0512 04:53:31.021577       1 util.go:182] Admission control plugin names: [NamespaceLifecycle MutatingAdmissionWebhook ValidatingAdmissionWebhook ServicePlanChangeValidator BrokerAuthSarCheck DefaultServicePlan ServiceBindingsLifecycle]
I0512 04:53:31.021949       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 6 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ServicePlanChangeValidator,BrokerAuthSarCheck,DefaultServicePlan,ServiceBindingsLifecycle.
I0512 04:53:31.021971       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 1 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: ValidatingAdmissionWebhook.
I0512 04:53:31.023932       1 storage_factory.go:285] storing {servicecatalog.k8s.io clusterservicebrokers} in servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1, reading as servicecatalog.k8s.io/__internal from storagebackend.Config{Type:"", Prefix:"/registry", ServerList:[]string{"https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379"}, KeyFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key", CertFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt", CAFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt", Quorum:true, Paging:true, DeserializationCacheSize:0, Codec:runtime.Codec(nil), Transformer:value.Transformer(nil), CompactionInterval:300000000000, CountMetricPollPeriod:60000000000}
I0512 04:53:31.023978       1 storage_factory.go:285] storing {servicecatalog.k8s.io clusterserviceclasses} in servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1, reading as servicecatalog.k8s.io/__internal from storagebackend.Config{Type:"", Prefix:"/registry", ServerList:[]string{"https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379"}, KeyFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key", CertFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt", CAFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt", Quorum:true, Paging:true, DeserializationCacheSize:0, Codec:runtime.Codec(nil), Transformer:value.Transformer(nil), CompactionInterval:300000000000, CountMetricPollPeriod:60000000000}
I0512 04:53:31.023998       1 storage_factory.go:285] storing {servicecatalog.k8s.io clusterserviceplans} in servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1, reading as servicecatalog.k8s.io/__internal from storagebackend.Config{Type:"", Prefix:"/registry", ServerList:[]string{"https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379"}, KeyFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key", CertFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt", CAFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt", Quorum:true, Paging:true, DeserializationCacheSize:0, Codec:runtime.Codec(nil), Transformer:value.Transformer(nil), CompactionInterval:300000000000, CountMetricPollPeriod:60000000000}
I0512 04:53:31.024031       1 storage_factory.go:285] storing {servicecatalog.k8s.io serviceinstances} in servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1, reading as servicecatalog.k8s.io/__internal from storagebackend.Config{Type:"", Prefix:"/registry", ServerList:[]string{"https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379"}, KeyFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key", CertFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt", CAFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt", Quorum:true, Paging:true, DeserializationCacheSize:0, Codec:runtime.Codec(nil), Transformer:value.Transformer(nil), CompactionInterval:300000000000, CountMetricPollPeriod:60000000000}
I0512 04:53:31.024055       1 storage_factory.go:285] storing {servicecatalog.k8s.io servicebindings} in servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1, reading as servicecatalog.k8s.io/__internal from storagebackend.Config{Type:"", Prefix:"/registry", ServerList:[]string{"https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379"}, KeyFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key", CertFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt", CAFile:"/etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt", Quorum:true, Paging:true, DeserializationCacheSize:0, Codec:runtime.Codec(nil), Transformer:value.Transformer(nil), CompactionInterval:300000000000, CountMetricPollPeriod:60000000000}
F0512 04:53:51.025999       1 storage_decorator.go:57] Unable to create storage backend: config (&{ /registry [https://cic-90-master.novalocal:2379] /etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.key /etc/origin/master/master.etcd-client.crt /etc/origin/master/master.etcd-ca.crt true true 0 {0xc420345080 0xc420345100} <nil> 5m0s 1m0s}), err (context deadline exceeded)
```

**Logs of controller-manager pods:-**

```
I0512 05:05:01.273888       1 feature_gate.go:194] feature gates: map[OriginatingIdentity:true]
I0512 05:05:01.274109       1 feature_gate.go:194] feature gates: map[OriginatingIdentity:true AsyncBindingOperations:true]
I0512 05:05:01.274128       1 feature_gate.go:194] feature gates: map[NamespacedServiceBroker:true OriginatingIdentity:true AsyncBindingOperations:true]
I0512 05:05:01.274155       1 hyperkube.go:192] Service Catalog version v3.11.0-0.1.35+8d4f895-2;Upstream:v0.1.35 (built 2019-01-08T23:12:26Z)
I0512 05:05:01.276689       1 leaderelection.go:185] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-service-catalog/service-catalog-controller-manager...
I0512 05:05:01.303464       1 leaderelection.go:194] successfully acquired lease kube-service-catalog/service-catalog-controller-manager
I0512 05:05:01.303609       1 event.go:221] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"kube-service-catalog", Name:"service-catalog-controller-manager", UID:"724069a9-9362-11ea-b5c1-fa163e86d97a", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"126373", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'LeaderElection' controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
F0512 05:05:01.332950       1 controller_manager.go:237] error running controllers: failed to get api versions from server: failed to get supported resources from server: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: servicecatalog.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

**Output of kubectl get events:-**

```
LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT     NAME                                                  KIND        SUBOBJECT                             TYPE      REASON           SOURCE                               MESSAGE
2h          2h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e29595b5f2ac8   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e29a1c8d44d5f   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e29e88bcdabf4   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2a2ea2d553cf   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2abce844b1a6   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2bd884a3fd98   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
1h          17h          183       apiserver-28mjt.160df6e8ab679328                      Pod         spec.containers{apiserver}            Normal    Pulled           kubelet, cic-90-master.novalocal     Container image "docker.io/openshift/origin-service-catalog:v3.11.0" already present on machine
1h          1h           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2c1f807c24b0   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
59m         59m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2cac5f27eb61   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
48m         48m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2d3d315161ed   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
43m         43m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2d84348e29c6   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
38m         38m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2dcbb5d88e66   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
33m         33m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2e13307a6011   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
23m         23m          1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2ea16c9db85d   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
8m          8m           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2f75c0f6468a   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
4m          17h          4491      apiserver-28mjt.160df6f2fa5c8d45                      Pod         spec.containers{apiserver}            Warning   BackOff          kubelet, cic-90-master.novalocal     Back-off restarting failed container
2m          2m           1         service-catalog-controller-manager.160e2fbf5d9a2418   ConfigMap                                         Normal    LeaderElection   service-catalog-controller-manager   controller-manager-jvx4f-external-service-catalog-controller became leader
2m          20h          5739      controller-manager-jvx4f.160dec6599cd8b00             Pod         spec.containers{controller-manager}   Warning   BackOff          kubelet, cic-90-master.novalocal     Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: share output of kubectl get events

Comment: And `kubectl logs` of the CLBO pods

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @ArghyaSadhu. Shared the output in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @mdaniel. Shared the logs in the question.

Comment: That `context deadline exceeded` _usually_ means `etcd` is unresponsive, and may be down, but since etcd uses mutual TLS authentication, it will (unfortunately) _also_ give that message when the client and server do not agree on the certificate chain of trust. It's way too intricate to troubleshoot over SO chat

Comment: Is your dns accessible when internet connection is down? My guess is that etcd is not staring because it cannot resolve dns names of etcd peers. Can you confirm that this is true (or false)?

Comment: yes, my dns is accessible and also my etcd pods are in running state @HelloWorld

Comment: @mdaniel my etcd pods are up and in running state, only the pods apiserver and controller-manager pods are not running.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated @HelloWorld